# What restrictions are there to building a tower near a private airstrip?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa

I'm exploring the possibility of putting up a radio tower on a property I own. The problem is that my property is roughly 1,000ft from a private airstrip. The location that I want to put the tower is not within the approach/departure path of the runway and is not under any navigational easements. The height that I'm looking at is roughly 150ft, just high enough to get approximately 20-30ft above the existing trees in the area. My question though is, what are FAA restrictions around building towers near private airports? Is it different from public airports? If so, is it possible to do this at all so close to an existing airport?

Comment: The FCC has a [web page](http://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsApp/AsrSearch/towairSearch.jsp) that you can fill out that tells whether you have to register the tower with them.

Comment: According to [this page](http://wirelessestimator.com/articles/2016/new-faa-rules-will-require-some-50-to-200-foot-towers-to-be-marked/) there are apparently some new regulations for towers 50-200 ft that goi into affect this month (Sep 2017).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this AC you *dont* need to light the structure](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_70_7460-1L_.pdf),

> Any temporary or permanent structure, including all appurtenances,
>   that **exceeds an overall height of 200 feet (61 m) above ground level**
>   (AGL) or exceeds any obstruction standard contained in [14 CFR Part 77](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:2.0.1.2.9#se14.2.77_117)
>   should be marked and/or lighted.

But the FAA does have special cases and since you are close to a strip they may require/recommend it,

> The FAA may also recommend marking and/or lighting a structure that
>   does not exceed 200 (61 m) feet AGL or [14 CFR Part 77](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:2.0.1.2.9#se14.2.77_117) standards
>   because of its particular location.

Looks like you need some [specific stuff to actually light it.](http://www.flightlight.com/obstruction-light/?gclid=CjwKCAjwranNBRBhEiwASu908LlIoJ8QDEDPz0bHtlkqs-PW3J8nnI91sHuh-NIEFoLlCmirJ_FBLhoCnzUQAvD_BwE) Your [local FSDO](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/) should be able to help out with what ever info you need. As far as I know these kinds of regulations don't change between public and private airports.

You can find the letter of the law for [14 CFR Part 77 here](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:2.0.1.2.9#se14.2.77_117). The most applicable to your case is quite possibly,

> (3) A height within a terminal obstacle clearance area, including an
>   **initial approach segment, a departure area, and a circling approach
>   area,** which would result in the vertical distance between any point on
>   the object and an established minimum instrument flight altitude
>   within that area or segment to be less than the required obstacle
>   clearance.

Even though you are not directly in line with the runway you may be in conflict with a potential traffic pattern or approach segment.

Comment: It is also a good idea to notify the FSDO just because they can add a NOTAM for the obstruction in the AFD (or d-CS as they are calling it now).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Seems like it's not entirely outside the realm of possibility then. I'll see what the FSDO says about it.

Comment: I guess rergulations are different [in Canada.](http://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDMDC-TSPA_0002826F&R=DC-TSPA_0002826F)

Comment: @KeithMcClary Ha! Yeah, I suppose so. In the U.S., that building permit would be denied... and if you built it anyway, I'd expect some bulldozers to be showing up in short order, especially at a public-use field.